# MySQL Connection Error in Elastic Beanstalk App (Tomcat 7)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently deploying a maven-built .war file to Elastic Beanstalk, using the 64-bit AmazonLinux Server for Tomcat 7.  However, the application, which runs fine off of localhost, is not running due to the following error (Stack Trace at the bottom):

> javax.naming.NamingException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I am connecting to an external Xeround instance. After reading around on the web, I attempted to modify my app's context.xml to this:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" //<- NOT THERE BEFORE
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    logAbandoned="true" 
    maxActive="100" 
    maxIdle="30" 
    maxWait="10000" 
    name="jdbc/xxxx-01292013" 
    password="xxxx" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://instancexxxx.db.xeround.com:xxxx/xxxx-01292013?   autoReconnect=true"
    username="xxxx-general"/>
```

Has anyone else had a problem uploading and using a previously working version to an Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat 7 app and found a way to get it working?

I have also read [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106493), but I don't know where to add in the .ebextensions file in a Netbeans maven project, and I don't understand what that would do.  Thanks for any help.

> 1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   myapp-persist] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory   at
>   com.berger.jpa.EntityInitializer.(EntityInitializer.java:12)
>   while locating com.berger.jpa.EntityInitializer
>       for field at com.nexuscop.startup.StartupListener.entityInit(StartupListener.java:40)
>   while locating com.nexuscop.startup.StartupListener
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwProvisionExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:451)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:944)
>     at
>   com.nexuscop.startup.StartupListener.(StartupListener.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   nexuscop-persist] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>     at com.berger.jpa.JpaPersistService.start(JpaPersistService.java:83)
>     at com.berger.jpa.EntityInitializer.(EntityInitializer.java:14)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:60)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not
>   find datasource   at
>   org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
>     ... 42 more Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:860)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)    at
>   org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)   at
>   org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656320/classnotfoundexception-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-tomcat-7 for the solution I found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people currently seem to be having trouble getting the .ebextensions approach to work at the moment.  Here is a work-around just to get up and running.  I wouldn't run in production like this, but I have used it to do test/debug when I got frustrated with .ebextensions.

You can put the mysql driver directly in your WAR.  If you are using Maven, just add this to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can also add this to the META-INF/context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      url="jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXX
       ... />
```

And put this in the pom.xml (Otherwise the BasicDataSourceFactory isn't found):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: +1 - Mark, what are you concerns about running in production like this?

Comment: Viccari - the mysql-connector-java should be installed in tomcat, not packaged in the WAR.  But even more suspicious about this approach is that the commons-dbcp and its dependencies are really part of the Tomcat framework and its redundant to have them on the WAR.  Could end up with classpath conflict if you have different versions fo the commons JARs in Tomcat vs. in the WAR.